# API for update an address

Tags: api, addresses

I'm testing the API in order to update some addressee informations (eg. the street_number) using the API Explore page.
In any test:

```
CRM.api3('Address', 'replace', {
  "id": 204,
  "street_number": 556
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

or

```
CRM.api3('Address', 'replace', {
  "contact_id": 202,
  "location_type_id": "Casa",
  "street_number_suffix": 556
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

I obtain the following result:

```
{

    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: values"
}
```

How can I set the key?

Answer (score 4):

@Zeno when you have create option you don't have to look for replace

please use create key word to create new or to update the record if record exist

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'create', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => 202,
  'location_type_id' => "Work",
  'street_address' => "test",
  'street_number_suffix' => 506,
));
```

Please try the above - This will work